# Set a new value to a NSString variable with a previous value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK and XCode.

This is a simple question but I don't know how to do it because I don't want any memory leaks on my code.

I'm using **ARC** on my project and I have the following header declaration:

```
@interface UserPreferences : NSObject
{
    NSUserDefaults* prefs;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString* appLanguage;

// More code

- (void) setAppLanguage:(NSString *)appLanguage;

// More code
@end
```

And this is how I've implemented `- (void) setAppLanguage:(NSString *)appLanguage;`.

```
- (void) setAppLanguage:(NSString *)newAppLanguage
{
    [prefs setObject:appLanguage forKey:APP_LANGUAGE_KEY];
    appLanguage = [NSString stringWithString:newAppLanguage];
}
```

Is `appLanguage = [NSString stringWithString:newAppLanguage];` correct?

I don't know it `appLanguage` will have a value when I set a new one to it.

**Is my code correct?**

Comment: If appLanguage is NSString and newAppLanguage is also NSString you dont need to do stringWithString:, you can just equate the two.appLanguage=newAppLanguage;

Comment: `appLanguage will have a value when I set a new one to it.` yes it will have, and new value will replace its previous value. You can simply write `@property (strong) NSString* appLanguage;` and your setAppLanguage to override the default setter. no need to make one readonly and then creating confusion my making it writ+read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't have any leaks; ARC automatically releases the previous value for `appLanguage` for you. I would write `appLanguage = [newAppLanguage copy]` rather than using `stringWithString:`, but the effect is the same.

Comment: Why would you bother copying an immutable NSString?

Comment: @JShapiro The problem is that ```newAppLanguage``` could be an NSMutableString (since it's a subclass of NSString), and so it could be mutated surprisingly unless you copy it first. (This is why Apple usually declares NSString, NSArray and similar objects as copy properties.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've omitted some code, this won't work...

You've created an instance variable for `NSUserDefaults`, but have never instantiated it with a value.  When you call `[prefs setObject:appLanguage forKey:APP_LANGUAGE_KEY];` `prefs` will be `nil.`

At some point, before you use `prefs`, you need to do something like: `prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

If you have instantiated prefs somewhere else, you'll still have an issue with this logic.  Presumably, you're trying to change the NSUserDefaults to the new language passed in.  In that case, the method should be:

```
- (void) setAppLanguage:(NSString *)newAppLanguage {
    _appLanguage = newAppLanguage; // implicit synchronize will set the ivar as _appLanguage
    [prefs setObject:newAppLanguage forKey:APP_LANGUAGE_KEY];
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

Since the `_appLanguage` instance variable is set to `strong` by default, ARC will automatically add the necessary `release` and `retain` code, preventing a memory leak.

Also, if you are trying to create a private setter method, take `- (void) setAppLanguage:(NSString *)appLanguage;` out of the interface.  If you're not trying to make a private setter, remove `readonly` from the property declaration.

Comment: I'm asking about how to set a new value to appLanguage.